# Strange behavior in boost::variant's handling of move-only types

Tags: c++, boost, c++17

Given the following:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201703L
    #include <variant>
    using std::variant;
#else
    #include <boost/variant.hpp>
    using boost::variant;
#endif
```

Consider this snippet. This compiles under both c++17's `std::variant<>` and `boost::variant<>`.

```
struct B
{
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) = delete;
    B(B&&) {}
    B& operator=(const B&&) = delete;
    B& operator=(B&&) {}
};

int main()
{
    variant<B, int> v;
    v = B{};
}
```

However, this other example only compiles with C++17's `std::variant<>`, since `boost::variant<>` attempts to perform a copy-assignment.

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {}
};

struct B
{
    B(int) {}
    B(const B&) = delete;
    B(B&&) {}
    B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
    B& operator=(B&&) {}
};

int main()
{
    variant<A, B> v{A{42}};
    v = B{42}; // This line doesn't compile with Boost
}
```

The only notable differences between the two examples are the presence of `struct A` and default constructors versus constructors taking an `int`. I have also found out that if the move constructor and assignment operator of `class B` in the second case are `= default`ed, it can be compiled using Boost. Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with Boost.Variant? Both examples where attempted using Boost 1.65 and GCC 7.2.0.

Comment: This compiles [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca73f64bf5839907)?

Comment: @Yuushi Yeah it's really weird. If you `= default` the move constructor, it compiles, but [otherwise, it doesn't](https://godbolt.org/g/Eu5n4N)

Comment: Maybe some of the MPL sorcery underlying Boost.Variant is checking for trivial move constructors/assignment operators when non-trivial ones should also be accepted?

Comment: What is the question? Currently it It looks like defect report to Boost.Variant.

Comment: @ÖöTiib: I intended to report this as a bug to the Boost tracker, but decided to ask here beforehand whether it's in effect a bug or is this somehow documented behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the move-constructor is not noexcept, which makes it unsuitable:

https://godbolt.org/g/368cjJ

```
B(B&&) noexcept {};
```

You can also write:

```
B(B&&) = default;
```

in which case the compiler implicitly generates a `noexcept` move constructor.

Comment: So, for a move-only type, its move-constructor/move-`operator=` must be `noexcept` for `variant` to accept it? Why can `std::variant` do without this requirement?

Comment: @3442 because it has been decided that `std::variant` could become [`valueless_by_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/valueless_by_exception), so that non-`noexcept` move constructors be suitable.

Comment: Thanks @Quentin: yes. In other words, Boost's [_never-empty-guarantee_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty) implies that move-construction _must_ be `noexcept`